# Plotting some piecewise functions in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Could you please tell me how can I plot functions that looks like:

```
f(x)=(x-1)^2 for 0 < x < 1 
f(x)=(x-8)^2 for 1<=x<=7
f(x)=x for x>7
```

in gnuplot.
(If you could tell how to call such a kind of function in English I try to change the topic to the more appropiate).

Comment: they are called piecewise functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in that way:

```
f(x)=x<=1 ? -(x-1)**2+1 :  x>7 ? (-48)*sin(240)+1+0.5*x : (-(x-1)**2+1)*sin(30*x)+1
plot f(x)
```

Comment: Note that you could also split this into multple functions (`f(x)`,`g(x)`,`h(x)` ...) e.g. `f(x)=(x<=1)?-(x-1)**2+1:1/0`.  The difference with this approach is that your plotted function will appear discontinuous (which might be desirable in some circumstances).